# xp_cmshell 'wlan show profile name="xxxx" key=clear'

Tags: sql, sql-server, netsh, wifi, xp-cmdshell

```
xp_cmdshell 'netsh wlan show profile name="xxxx"'
```

It gives me information about my Wifi network.

But when I am trying to use the same command with  "**key=clear**"

```
xp_cmdshell 'netsh wlan show profile name="XXX" key=clear'
```

I am getting back the same result without password. Just information ABSENT/PRESENT
I have no idea how to show password. 
Do I have need higher security account or It is just disabled due to security reasons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed in SQL Configuration Manager - SQL Server instance proporties -> Log On card, the Log on Account to Local System and restarted service. It solved problem.